# Close blades and update URL Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I love Angular 2; it's awesome but at some point I feel stuck with a few issues

I have tried to make an app with three sections, and the URL should be something like this: mysite.com/blade1/blade2/blade3, now the problem:

Every blade has a Close icon on the top, when you press it, the blade closes and also updated the URL ([Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNYtL.png)), a few examples:

- Close Blade2 = mysite.com/blade1/blade3
- Close Blade 3 = mysite.com/blade1/blade2

Any thoughts about how to do it? I have read a lot about routing but I can't get the solution.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: I am going to make an Plunk and I will share it